# OpenAPI angular/typescript client generator appending numbers to methods with same name even if they are in separated controllers

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator

I have a Spring Boot API and an Angular 12 app the consumes it.

Additionally I use OpenAPI CLI to generate the typescript client for the Angular app to use.
In my API, all controllers have a method named search with the same params.
The problem I'm having is that the generated api call has a number added to the name like
controller1 search will become search
controller2 search will become search1

Those number change every time a new client version is generated which forces me to rewrite code to use the appropriate names...

To generate the client I run:

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files\openapi-6.0.1\openapi-generator-cli-6.0.1.jar" generate -i http://localhost:9999/v3/api-docs -g typescript-angular -o ./client/ --additional-properties ngVersion=10,npmName=angular-eforms-client,npmVersion=0.0.1 --type-mappings=set=Array,DateTime=Date
```

Is any config to stop this?
I've tried adding

```
@Operation(operationId = "search")
```

to the API's methods, but it didn't seem to matter.

Thanks